# Will a mounted drive get encrypted with the parent directory?

Tags: mount, encryption, ecryptfs, mountpoint

I have a secondary drive mounted at /home/user/Storage , will encrypting my home directory with ecryptfs encrypt the contents of the secondary drive as well?

Comment: No, mount doesn't work like that. I'm sure I've seen an identical Q before...